# Join specific number of rows from one table to a single row of another one

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently generating random data and I'm not sure how to do this part.
I have two tables. I have one entity table and a group table. Both tables have a unique identifiers (guid). My goal is to create a table mappings that matches entities X amount of times to a single group.

For example, let's say I have 10k entities and 100 groups and I would like to create 1k mappings. I would need to create 10 mappings per group (1000/100). I could go ahead and create a while loop and just get 10 random entities, but it is not efficient and I would like to avoid that. I also thought about cross join and then reduce the result to 1k, but I would like each group to have the exact same number of mappings.

Is there any way to do this with a single query ?

Here is an example, say I have this `Group table` and `Entity Table`

```
+---------+
| GroupId |
+---------+
| G1      |
| G2      |
| G3      |
+---------+
+----------+
| EntityId |
+----------+
| E1       |
| E2       |
| E3       |
| E4       |
| E5       |
| E6       |
| E7       |
| E8       |
| E9       |
| E10      |
+----------+

I would like to get 6 mappings (so each group needs 2 mappings). Here is an example of what I could get:

+---------+----------+
| GroupId | EntityId |
+---------+----------+
| G1      | E2       |
| G1      | E4       |
| G2      | E9       |
| G2      | E10      |
| G3      | E2       |
| G3      | E5       |
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data / desired results.

Comment: You could write a cte with rownumber, join it onto groups on rownumber/1000 = group number(or rownumber of group subquery) and update the CTE to assign group numbers to a column in the CTE which, bring 1:1 is updatable (like a view)

Comment: @Kendle I always have a hard time with CTE. I did manage to do it with a loop and temp tables that create a rownumber for each time, then randomize the entities with `ORDER BY NEWID()`, and then match by rownum and bonds of amount of entities per group, but yeah it is really not that efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good use for [NTILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Start by using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the `Groups` table to generate sequential "group numbers" (sort by [NewID()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for a  *relatively* random order):

> ```
> GroupId | GroupNum
> :------ | -------:
> G3      |        1
> G2      |        2
> G1      |        3
> ```

Then use [NTILE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to distribute the `Entity` rows into the desired number of groups:

> ```
> E1  | GroupNum
> :-- | -------:
> E2  |        1
> E10 |        1
> E3  |        1
> E4  |        1
> E1  |        2
> E6  |        2
> E5  |        2
> E7  |        3
> E8  |        3
> E9  |        3
> ```

Finally JOIN the results together on "group number":

**SQL:**

> ```
> DECLARE @NumOfGroups INT;
>
> SET @NumOfGroups = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Groups );
>
> SELECT e.[E1], g.GroupId
> FROM  (
>         SELECT  *, NTILE(@NumOfGroups) OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) AS GroupNum 
>         FROM    Entities 
>       ) 
>       AS e 
>       INNER JOIN 
>       (
>          SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) AS GroupNum
>          FROM   Groups
>       )  
>       AS g ON g.GroupNum = e.GroupNum
> ORDER BY e.GroupNum, e.E1
> GO
> ```

**Results:**

| E1 | GroupId |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | G1 |
| E3 | G1 |
| E5 | G1 |
| E8 | G1 |
| E2 | G3 |
| E7 | G3 |
| E9 | G3 |
| E10 | G2 |
| E4 | G2 |
| E6 | G2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3aa01cb7d13c963679401959f1e3cc6e)*

**NB: Obviously this approach won't work if there are less `Entity` rows than `Groups`, but it doesn't sound like that's an issue here**

Comment: wow that's exactly what I needed, thanks a lot